# Ethers function not found

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, solidity, hardhat

I’ve just been going through the documentation of hardhat and I ran into an issue early on.

When I try to deploy using the below hardhat function:

```
async function deployTokenFixture() {
    const hardhatToken = await ethers.deployContract("Token");

    await hardhatToken.waitForDeployment();
}
```

I get this error: `hardhatToken.waitForDeployment is not a function`.

I am fairly sure there is something wrong with my Ethers library, but I am not sure how to fix it.

I tried reinstalling the ethers library running

```
npm install @nomiclabs/ethers
```

As well as

```
npm install @nomiclabs/hardhat-deploy-ethers
```

Neither of which addressed my problem

Comment: What is your `hardhat` version?

Comment: @RobinThomas I’m running 2.17.3

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, see if it works:

```
  // Deploy the contract
  const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
  const hardhatToken = await Token.deploy();

  // Wait for the deployment to complete
  await hardhatToken.deployed();

  // Now the contract is deployed and ready to use
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to versions. Function `waitForDeployment()` did not support in few versions back. You have two options,

1. Update hardhat to the newest version.
2. Use `await hardhatToken.deployed();` instead.